# Blogspot API (updated-min & updated-max flaky?)

Tags: blogspot

I need to access all the posts from a blogspot blog in chronological fashion. I've thus had to rely almost solely on the updated-min and updated-max parameters provided by the Blogspot API.

However, I've found that the accuracy of these two parameters leaves a lot to be desired. Sometimes I'll query for a feed using a particular updated-min but the feed won't 'go back in time' far enough. It will stop short by a few posts. I've been compensating for this particular issue by minusing 3 hours and adding 7 seconds to each updated-min. That's somehow been able to fix it. Now the feeds I get are acceptable. I'm just wondering if this is a known issue or whether or not I'm needlessly overcomplicating a simple problem.

Thanks in advance fellas.

incidentally this is my first question ever on here, so if this question doesn't fit here, or I've committed some sort of egregious offence then it was all done by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

A week later, and my 'hack' is still reeling in acceptable feeds. I don't know how long this is going to hold up. I'm still really disappointed in blogspot api's unreliability and the general lack of info concerning this issue on the web. if anybody ever finds this q on the web, i'd be glad to hear what your thoughts are on this.